# An script for automatic page creation per term

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, polylang

My site is such that it introduces the devices and displays their specifications (something like WooCommerce but without the ability to buy),
I have 2 Post-Types named "Devices" and "Companies" where all the devices and companies are located in the respective sections, which are connected to their respective terms; I have 3 terms named Device, Company, and Service. These 3 terms make these post-types link to each other (or maybe there is a more optimal way, but I don't know).
My questions are:

1. Is it possible that there is no need to create a Post_type anymore? I use JetEngine and save all the information and parameters of each device in my Term so that I can use it in Elementor.
2. Is there a plugin that can automatically create a Post_type for each relevant term (along with some custom fields automatically)? For example, if I create something called Microsoft in Term Company, the plugin will automatically create a page in Post_type Companies. In addition, my site is in two languages (Persian and English), and I use the PolyLang plugin, and because of this, my work has become more difficult, because I have to manually create a page for each term in Post_Type, that too Along with Custom Fields related to that language!
   If you provide a script, please explain how to use it because I don't know much.

there were no plugins i could be able to find for this situation.

Comment: Can you write your own plugin for that?

Comment: well, I don't know coding to be able to create a plugin.

Comment: Try https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/